# iOS release a touch event to load data into a UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, touch-event

I have a UIWebview that is scrollable and loads text from an array. They're previous and next buttons to allow the user to get the last or next content.

If a user holds down the scrollable content of the UIWebview and taps next, the text in the UIWebview will not load the next data until the user releases their finger from the screen.

How to I cancel the touch from the screen momentarily when the user taps the previous or next buttons.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, switching off and back on a gesture will force it to cancel.

Edit: I was on my cellphone before, so I'll just add more details to my answer.

If your using iOS 5 and up, you can probably try something like this in your button action (I'm not on a Mac right now so I didn't test):

```
- (IBAction)yourAction:(id)sender {
    [webView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [webView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    //The rest of your code...
}
```

The reason I'm saying iOS 5 and up is because before iOS 5, the scrollView of a `UIWebView` wasn't exposed. If you're not using iOS 5, you have to resort to [iterating through the subviews](http://blog.andrewpaulsimmons.com/2010/02/controlling-uiscrollview-in-uiwebview.html) of your webView to find a `UIScrollView`.